# TensorFlow repeat function fails with ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: tensorflow, keras, repeat

I have implemented the following custom `Layer` that modify the size of a learnable parameter `seed_vectors` upon call according to the size of input `x` using the function `repeat`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import repeat
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization


class PoolingMultiHeadAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, d, k, h):
        """
        Arguments:
            d: an integer, input dimension.
            k: an integer, number of seed vectors.
            h: an integer, number of heads.
        """
        super(PoolingMultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.seed_vectors = self.add_weight(initializer='uniform',
                                            shape=(1, k, d),
                                            trainable=True)

    def call(self, z):
        """
        Arguments:
            z: a float tensor with shape [b, n, d].
        Returns:
            a float tensor with shape [b, k, d]
        """
        b = z.shape[0]
        s = self.seed_vectors
        s = repeat(s, (b), axis=0, name='rep')  # shape [b, k, d]
        return s*z


# Dimensionality test    
z = tf.random.normal(shape=(10, 2, 9))
pma = PoolingMultiHeadAttention(d=9, k=2, h=3)
pma(z)
```

I have tested dimensionality input/output in unit tests and it works fine, but unfortunately if I use this Layer inside a Model it fails with error:

```
    <ipython-input-4-89023d123369>:110 call  *
        s = repeat(s, (b), axis=0, name='rep')  # shape [b, k, d]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:5616 repeat  **
        return repeat_with_axis(input, repeats, axis, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:5478 repeat_with_axis
        repeats = convert_to_int_tensor(repeats, name="repeats")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:5388 convert_to_int_tensor
        tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(tensor, name=name, preferred_dtype=dtype)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1341 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:317 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:258 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:296 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:439 make_tensor_proto
        raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

    ValueError: None values not supported.
```

This error seems to be related to the lack of an output (or output is None) [which I know it is not the case as I have tested the function in eager mode and it works] or for some reason backprop does not work with this op (`repeat`).
I do not know of any alternative way to modify the size of that parameter at runtime + (almost) the same code works fine using Pytorch (https://github.com/TropComplique/set-transformer/blob/master/blocks.py)
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix should be quite simple: use `b = tf.shape(z)[0]` instead. Explanation:

The problem is that you are trying to repeat `b` times, which (I suppose) is the variable batch size. When not running in eager mode, this is represented by the value `None` in the shape. Thus, you are trying to repeat "None times" which leads to a crash.

The important thing is that `Tensor.shape` returns the *static* shape of the tensor, i.e. whatever is known at compile time. This includes `None` for unknown dimensions as noted above.
`tf.shape(tensor)` instead returns the *dynamic* shape, i.e. this will be evaluated only when the model is run. At this time, the batch size if of course known (since you put something into the model) and so this will turn out to be a concrete value that can be put into `repeat`, as opposed to the `None` we got above.